# fix hotspot image on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

i changed the display of hotspots but I want to fix the hotspots location on the screen rather than on the photo. I want hotspots to follow the screen when I navigate through the panoramic view can i do this ?
I want to give perspective to hotspots my goal is to get hotspots more flat on the ground

```
 .pnlm-hotspot-base {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  cursor: default;
  vertical-align: middle;
  left: 0px;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: skewX(-50deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 30%;
}

.custom-hotspot-front {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 55px;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-image: url("forward.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 0px;
  transform: skewX(-50deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 30%;
}
.custom-hotspot-front:hover {
  background-color: rgba(173, 239, 255, 0.5);
  perspective: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work,
[I want to do something like this;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsAbN.jpg)

Is it possible to do this with css?

[and the image of the hotspots that I have obtained looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNM1K.jpg)

Comment: Hi, please add more info and include enough runnable code so we can help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I added the more detailed css codes above

Comment: Please include the relvant HTML and also describe what 'didn't work' means - what did you see compared to what you wanted to see and have you inspected in your browser devtools to see what is setting the positioning?

Comment: There is some CSS at the end which doesn't seem to be related to a selector. Could you correct that as well?

Comment: There is no line of code related to this topic in HTML. I am using the Pannellum library to view panoramic photos. I updated the hotspot image in the library to "forward.png". Like the url I want to do ; [link] (https://www.mapillary.com/app/?lat=41.0196162&lng=28.865822699972&z=17&panos=true&pKey=4793583114057140&focus=photo&x=0.4590080846246491&y=0.4875008252998415&zoom=0) 
I want to get a hotspot that moves with me when I rotate the screen like the hotspots found here

Comment: `transform-style: preserve-3d; transform: translateZ(-100px);` i added this line of code as a solution